# How to install Infopath Designer 2013 and Software Requirements

Tags: infopath, forms-services, infopath-rules

I'm new in Infopath development, trying to develop Infopath forms from my local machine.

Does anyone have some information related to Infopath like:

- Downloadlink for InfoPath (Designer) 2013
- How to Install Infopath 2013
- Prerequisites for Infopath development
- How to start with Infopath forms etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At first, you need to install [Office Pro Plus 2013](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/evalcenter/evaluate-office-professional-plus-2013) which includes InfoPath Designer 2013 (and InfoPath Filler 2013). For [system requirements](https://products.office.com/en-us/office-system-requirements) you'll need at least a 1 GHz processor and 1 GB RAM (32 bit) or 2 GB RAM (64 bit). And of course 3 GB HDD available space.

To start develop, there are numerous of guides available, but a good place to start is at Microsoft Developer Center which links to valuable resources to get started with [InfoPath 2013](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj602751.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

InfoPath Designer is part of the Office suite. Depending on your Office license it will be included. To install it, just run the Office installer and make sure to select it as a component to be installed on your PC.

If you point your favorite search engine towards terms like "Infopath tutorial", you will find many, many materials on getting started.